# Как получить соседей двухмерного массива?

Tags: javascript

Есть двухмерный массив, мне необходимо получить соседей каждого элемента массива, как это сделать?

```js
let arr = []
let i = 0;

while (i < 30) {
  arr[i] = []
  let j = 0
  while (j < 30) {
    arr[i][j] = 0;
    j++
  }
  i++;
};

let arr2 = []

function neighbors(arr) {
  for (let i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    arr2[i] = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < 30; j++) {
      let neighbors = 0;

      if (arr[i + 1][j] == 0) neighbors++; // верх
      if (arr[i - 1][j] == 0) neighbors++; // вниз
      if (arr[i][j - 1] == 0) neighbors++; // влево
      if (arr[i][j + 1] == 0) neighbors++; // вправо
      if (arr[i - 1][j - 1] == 0) neighbors++; // верх-влево
      if (arr[i - 1][j + 1] == 0) neighbors++; // верх-вправо
      if (arr[i + 1][j - 1] == 0) neighbors++; // вниз-влево
      if (arr[i + 1][j + 1] == 0) neighbors++; // вниз-вправо

      arr2[i].push(neighbors)
    }
  }
  return arr2;
}
console.log(neighbors(arr))
```

https://codepen.io/dmytrik/pen/dyyymEz

Comment: ссылка на другой вопрос, скорее всего не правильная

Comment: и код, пожалуйста, в вопрос

Comment: что не так с кодом в вопросе?

Comment: выдает undefind, потому что инкрименты принимают значения, элементов которых нету в массиве

Comment: так а какие вы проверки имеете ввиду?